# Why does MS Teams establishing outbound connection towards malicious IP?

Tags: network, malware, windows, ip, microsoft

I'm wondering how come an internal "Teams.exe" can make outbound connections to a malicious IP, 132.147.119[.]217 (ISP: ViewQwest Pte Ltd) that was flagged as malicious and also was involved in abusive activities according to threat intelligence sources.

```
Process Tree: [1] explorer.exe > [2] update.exe > [3] teams.exe > [4] teams.exe

CLI:
[1] C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE

[2] "C:\ProgramData\mahxxxxxj\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe" --processStart "Teams.exe" --process-start-args "--system-initiated"

[3] "C:\ProgramData\mahxxxxxj\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe" --system-initiated

[4] "C:\ProgramData\mahxxxxxj\Microsoft\Teams\current\Teams.exe" --type=renderer --enable-wer --user-data-dir="C:\Users\mahxxxxxj\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Teams" --ms-teams-less-cors=522133263 --app-user-model-id=com.squirrel.Teams.Teams --app-path="C:\ProgramData\mahxxxxxj\Microsoft\Teams\current\resources\app.asar" --no-sandbox --no-zygote --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required --disable-background-timer-throttling --field-trial-handle=1732,4754145742863852652,6853269127876990418,131072 --enable-features=ContextBridgeMutability,SharedArrayBuffer,WinUseBrowserSpellChecker,WinUseHybridSpellChecker --disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,ExtraCookieValidityChecks,ForcedColors,MediaFoundationAsyncH264Encoding,PlzServiceWorker,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand --lang=en-US --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=4700 --msteams-process-type=pluginHost /prefetch:1

Netconnections:
2022-11-08 09:32:07.792 GMT netconn Connection to 132.147.119.217 on udp/10903
2022-11-08 09:32:07.805 GMT netconn Connection to 132.147.119.217 on udp/15528
```

Please find the related activity details above. Kindly advise on this please, thank you.

Comment: Flagged as malicious by whom? And did you note that it was an update to Team process?